# Proving that $(\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z})^*=\langle{}5 \, \text{mod} \, 23\rangle$

Tags: group-theory, modular-arithmetic

I don't quite understand what's going on here, and more primarily I don't see what they're asking either. We have to show that the set of all integers modulo 23 is equal to that of the set generated by 5 modulo 23 right? Why does the order of 5 mod 23 play a role here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: That means your group is cyclic, generated by $5$.

Comment: Yes but in order to prove the statement, I have to show that the one group is the subset of the other, and vice versa, and I don't see how I can go on about doing that

Comment: You prove, every element can be written as a  $5$-th power

Comment: It is actually sufficient to show that $5^2 \not\equiv 1 \bmod 23$, which is clear, and that $5^{11} \not\equiv 1 \bmod 23$, which involves a little more work, but doesn't really take very long.

Comment: I suggest you start by doing some computation. List all the powers of $5$ modulo $23$ and think about what you see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\newcommand{\z}{\left(\mathbb Z \over 23 \mathbb Z\right)^*}$

> I have to prove that one group is subset of the other, and vice versa.

That is one way of doing it. Not the way here.

Here, the fact that $\langle 5 \mod 23\rangle$ is a subset of $\z$ should be obvious. If this is not, then you need to look back at your definitions.

Now, just show they have the same size! That of course, will show that they are equal.

The size of $\z$ is $22$.

The order of $5$ mod $23$, is exactly the *size of the group* generated by the element $5$. If the order was equal to $22$, then this means that $\langle5 \pmod{23}\rangle$ has size $22$ and is a subgroup of a group of size $22$ itself, since $\z$ has size $22$. This would therefore show the equality that you want to show.

So all you need to show is that the order of $5$ mod $23$ is equal to $22$.

The idea of using the order is to simplify the process of showing equality. Yes, you will want to show that one is a subset of the other and vice-versa, but the reason why we have tools like order and so on is because they simplify things very well.

Finding the order of $5$ mod $23$ is tantamount, by Lagrange's theorem, to checking whether or not $5^d \equiv 1 \mod 23$ for every proper divisor $d$ of $22$, something far easier than showing explicitly that one is a subset of the other.

Comment: @DerekHolt How so? The size of $(\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z})^*$ is $22$ and not $23$

Comment: Yes but the star has been added since I wrote my comment!

Comment: Oh wait I see what you mean, the size of $\mathbb{Z}/23\mathbb{Z}$ is indeed 23

Comment: Yes, I had to edit the answer, so that comment is obsolete.